# Alignment of "view all" button in a list

Tags: design-patterns, design-principles

I'm designing a dashboard to allow users get a quick overview of updates and usage. So on the dashboard, there would be different widgets;

[image: dashboard]

Some of these widgets would be a short summary in a list format, with an option to "view more", where user can click and go to the respective page for a more complete view.

**I would like to find out if there are any ux standards/best practices for how the "view all" button should be aligned with respect to the list (left, middle, right)?**

[image: list widget]

Appreciate if anyone could point me to any existing frameworks that suggest a standard for this behaviour as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns can get wide to the point where there's lots of negative space to the right of the row value, the link label won't be so salient when the content is scanned. I'd go for left alignment for maximum discoverability (mirror the alignment for RTL languages).

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to [Ro's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/144519/67216) (and since it begins with an "If ..." ;) I'd choose *right* (for my LTR culture zone) because:

1. left-aligned has so much whitespace to the right, so there's a long way to go from the '>' into the whiteout before I reach...another page,
2. the '>' at the margin to the very right tells me that I'm about to leave here immediately...to another page,
3. all (standard) UI dialogs I'm aware of have their action buttons (<kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, <kbd>Yes</kbd>, <kbd>No</kbd>, ...) placed bottom-right since ever,
4. the <kbd>Next ></kbd> button on any [(standard) UI dialog within a sequence](http://download.blast2go.com/b2gusermanual/test/Addloadsequence.png) I'm aware of is at the bottom – most right to the left of the action buttons mentioned above if there are any, bottom-right otherwise,
5. any multi-page document on the web, that has [Prev](https://www.example.org), [Top](https://www.example.org)/[TOC](https://www.example.org), [Next](https://www.example.org) navigation links, I'm aware of has its [Next >](https://www.example.org) link bottom-right,
6. [E-Book-Reader](https://www.preisvergleich.ch/admin_upload/text-images/1130/1e50d25f10001eb55a2d840877719e55-20201130100041-ebook1.jpg)

Ad 4., 5. & 6.:  ... and you're sending me to a *next* page.

I support the mirroring for RTL. The link text should be "< view all" then or "< مشاهدة الكل" for that matter. :)